# C declaring a two-dimensional array using constants

Tags: c, arrays, constants

I have a header file for a game that declares a two-dimensional array for a board.

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

static const int columns = 15;
static const int rows = 15;

int board[rows][columns];

#endif /* GAME_H_ */
```

I get an error:

> error: variably modified 'board' at file scope

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C doesn't allow `const` variables as array bounds. Use an enum instead:

```
enum { columns = 15, rows = 15 };
```

Answer (score 3):

That expression is not allowed, it can be used in C++, the only way around this is to define it like this:

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#define COLUMNS 15
#define ROWS 15

int board[ROWS][COLUMNS];

#endif /* GAME_H_ */
```

Answer (score 3):

As of C99, you can declare what is known as a *variable length array* (VLA) where the size of the array dimension is a non-constant expression; IOW, you can do this:

```
int foo()
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
  int values[x][y];
  ...
}
```

Note that this is *only* true for C99; C89 and earlier requires you to use compile-time constant expressions for the array dimension.

The problem with VLAs is that, because of how they work, they may only be declared at *block scope* (that is, within a function or a compound statement in the function); they may not be declared as `static` or `extern`, and they may not be declared at file scope (which is the source of your particular error message).

In this particular case, you will need to use compile-time constant expressions (which `const`-qualified variables are *not*):

```
#define COLUMNS 15
#define ROWS    15

extern int board[ROWS][COLUMNS];
```

Note the addition of the `extern` keyword in the array declaration.  You don't want the declaration in the header file to be the *defining* declaration for the array; instead, put the *defining* declaration in the source file that actually implements the game board.  Otherwise every source file that includes that header will try to create its own definition for `board` and it will be up to the linker to sort it all out.

Answer (score 2):

```
int board[rows][columns];
```

is not valid C.  You can only define an array with a constant, not with a variable reference. Even if the variable reference refers to a value that is constant, rows and columns are references to the constant values an not the constant values themselves.

There are a number of ways to get this to work as you want:

1. You could define the "variables" in the preprocessor, so they get flattened into constants just before compile time.
2. You could define the values as part of an enumeration `enum` as the C compiler's rules for enumerations is to automatically covert them to their constant values whenever a type mismatch is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Array declarations need a constant value before compilation. You can #define variables in it or use pointers to make it work like an array. Both ways are fine will give you same results and simplicity.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works just fine in C++.

Comment: *or use pointers to make it work like an array*  No, you **can't**.  Pointers are not arrays, and arrays are not pointers.