# Variably modified array at file scope in C

Tags: c, arrays, static

I have some code like this:

```
static int a = 6;
static int b = 3;

static int Hello[a][b] =
{
    { 1,2,3},
    { 1,2,3},
    { 1,2,3},
    { 1,2,3},
    { 1,2,3},
    { 1,2,3}
};
```

But when I compile it, it says error:

> variably modified 'Hello' at file scope

How could this happen? And how could I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variably modified array at file scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712592/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope)

Comment: @tstew: No, that is for Objective-C

Comment: Related: *["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032)* and *[static const vs #define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen (and others) - I've flagged a few questions as duplicates of this (I think they should all appear as Linked in the right-hand column).  It would be great if you could browse them and close-vote the ones I'm right about.

Comment: Note: The title is partly literal and *"variably"* is part of the (literal) error message. [E.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881918/error-with-c-code), *"`variably modified ‘child’ at file scope`"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen The technically correct and formal term is _Variable length array_. I don't really see why we can't use the most correct term, especially if this post is to be used as canonical dupe.

Comment: @Lundin: We can. I don't have any objections. It was just to explain the origin of the weird word "variably".

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can not have a static array whose size is given as a variable.

That's why constants should be `#define`d:

```
#define a 6
```

This way, the preprocessor will replace `a` with `6`, making it a valid declaration.

Comment: is a and b defined as int a = 6; int b = 3 instead of static int a = 6 works?

Comment: No, this will still be a variable. Use `#define`. In C++ there is `const` that would allow `const int a = 6;` to work, but even `const` is not enough in C.

Comment: an alternative to macro is using anonymous enums, which are true integer constants
`enum { a = 6, b = 3, };`

Answer (score 11):

Simple answer: *A variable modified array at file scope is not possible*.

Detailed:

Make it a compile time *integral constant expression*, since the array length must be specified at the compile time.

Like this:

```
#define a 6
#define b 3
```

Or, follow the [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) standard. and compile like for [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection).

`gcc -Wall -std=c99 test.c -o test.out`

The problem here is a variable-length array with providing length may not be initialized, so you are getting this error.

Simply

```
static int a = 6;
static int b = 3;

void any_func()
{
    int Hello [a][b]; // No need of initialization. No static array means no file scope.
}
```

Now use a *for* loop or any loop to fill the array.

For more information, just a *demo*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int a = 6;
int main()
{
    int Hello[a] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; // See here initialization of the array 'Hello'. It's in the function
                                       // Scope, but still an error
    return 0;
}
```

#### Compile

```
cd ~/c
clang -std=c99 vararr.c -o vararr
```

Output:

```
vararr.c:8:11: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
int Hello[a]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
          ^
1 error generated.
```

If you remove static and provide initialization then it will generate the error as above.

But if you keep static as well as initialization then it will still be an error.

But if you remove the initialization and keep `static`, the below error will come.

```
error: variable length array declaration not allowed at file scope
static int Hello[a];
           ^     ~
1 error generated.
```

So a variable-length array declaration is not allowed at file scope, so make it function or block scope inside any function (but remember making it function scope must remove initialization)

*Note*: Since it's `C` tagged, making `a` and `b` as `const` won't help you, but in `C++` `const` will work fine.

Comment: C99 doesn't support VLA's at file-scope either. it must be at function-scope or smaller. He 'can' use **const** index declarations, including `static const int a = 10;` for example, at file scope.

Comment: Its a stack-thing. If they're even supported by your C99 compiler, it isn't mandated that they be; the standard defines *how* they behave *if* your C99 *does* support them. The implementations use stack-math to implement them. You can't do that at global (or file) data-segment compilation level.

Comment: @WhozCraig: But when I define `a` in `main` in that case also it's not working, compiling with `-std=c99` . now `a` is on stack so what's the problem now , I have tried with `gcc` and `clang`

Comment: @WhozCraig: I read somewhere on SO itself so posted the answer , but I am now myself facing this with `-std=c99` and not compiling, any clue ? going to edit my answer also

Comment: @WhozCraig : I got it ,YOu are wrong about stack- thing it could be global

Comment: Please show me how, as I've tried in the past to have VLA's globally declared and every compiler I've ever used puked on them. Its definitely worth an up-vote if you would, please.

Comment: @Omkant, you could add that the other kind of `integral constant expression`s that could be used here are enumeration constants.

Comment: @WhozCraig : see my answer , and tell me agreed or not , http://ideone.com/f1AykV for correct , http://ideone.com/VV12D5 , for error.It's just a demo I did.

Comment: @Omkant, you really worsened your answer with your edit. Neither the `[][]` nor with `static int Hello[a][b]` are valid C.

Comment: what confuses me is why `static size_t const size` wouldn't work for the size of an array at file scope. It works in function scope even in C89, so I would expect an object that is constant and is known at compile and load time to be able to be used there. Unless `static` is the problem, which sucks because I would like to keep them tied to the one compilation module.

Comment: actually, this only happens if the array is a `static uint8_t[]`. The compiler has no problem doing it for `static char[]`. But then, when I try to set up a repl.it to demonstrate this (mind you, this was after having already demonstrated the error in an anonymous repl.it and copy/pasting the exact code from that repl.it into a named repl.it), it just compiles without issue.

Comment: I ran into this issue while I was writing a brainfuck VM in C, while creating the physical memory and assigning pointers into it for the program counter and virtual memory.

Answer (score 4):

When using [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang)/[LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM), the following works:

```
static const int a = 6;
static const int b = 3;

static int Hello[a][b] =
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2, 3}
};
```

(To see it in the generated assembly, one needs to use 'Hello', so it will not be optimized out.)

However, this will generate an error if [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) mode is selected ([-std=c99](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-std)). It will only generate a warning (Wgnu-folding-constant) if [-pedantic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1) is selected.

=== EDIT ===
Clang now (version 14.0.0) generates this warning as default:
warning: variable length array folded to constant array as an extension [-Wgnu-folding-constant]

GCC does not seem to allow this (const is interpreted as read-only).

See the explanation in this question:

*["Initializer element is not constant" error for no reason in Linux GCC, compiling C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592494/initializer-element-is-not-constant-error-for-no-reason-in-linux-gcc-compilin)*

Comment: The 'const' keyword in C does not really mean 'constant'. This misleads some users.

Comment: @Lowpower I agree - this is a detail of the implementation. Moreover the actual implementation of cost seems to vary, in C++ at least some const are no longer 'read only variable (meaning there is no  symbol in the symbol table pointing to read-only memory segment) but true constants resolved at compile-time.

Comment: Neither clang nor gcc allows this to compile _cleanly_, because it is invalid C and a non-standard compiler extension. Notably a program could "just have warnings" and still be invalid C.

Comment: @Lundin
This apparently changed (which is good) since I wrote the answer, Clang now generates the warning: "variable length array folded to constant array as an extension"  (-Wgnu-folding-constant) by default.  The code is still "valid" - if that means accepted by the compiler and works s expected  (like all extensions) but is not standard.

Comment: If something goes against a constraint or syntax rule in the standard, then it is invalid C - it is not C but something else - "C with extensions". Compiler extensions might often violate constraints/syntax, but doing so will leave the compiler non-conforming unless it gives a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of the array must be constant expressions and your friend 'compiler' must be informed about that. So tell to compiler that a and b are constant values.

```
static constexpr int a = 6;

static constexpr int b = 3;

static int Hello[a][b] = { { 1,2,3 }, { 1,2,3 }, { 1,2,3 }, { 1,2,3 }, { 1,2,3 }, { 1,2,3 } };
```

Comment: Use 'const' for older C/ C++