# Error with C code: "variably modified ‘child’ at file scope"

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int b = 10; // maximum branching

typedef struct depth * depth;

struct depth{
    int number ;
    depth child[b] ;// <---- Error here
};
```

And the following error:

> variably modified ‘child’ at file scope

Comment: You can't have a variable array dimension.

Comment: you cant use a variable in array declaration. try using pointer and malloc it later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
#define MAX_BRANCHING 10

int b = MAX_BRANCHING; // maximum branching 

typedef struct depth * depth;

struct depth{
   int number ;
   depth child[MAX_BRANCHING] ;//<---- Error here 
};
```

"Variable length arrays" (VLAs) were introduced in C99 and C11, but their use is "conditional" (compilers are not *required* to implement the feature).  In C++, the preferred technique is to use "const int".  In C, I would recommend using a `#define`.  IMHO...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Comment: Other than "const", you have two choices: 1) make "depth" the max possible size, or 2) make "depth" a pointer, and intialize it with `malloc(b * sizeof (int))` at runtime.

Comment: mmmmm ,b must be entered by user , i cant make it constant !!

Comment: okay , thank you , i will make it max possible size , but i think that affect on space, i mean that it will take more space , since i want to code "Depth First algorithm"

Answer (score 1):

If `b` can't be constant, and you don't want to use *heap allocation* for the child array, you can use this, rather peculiar workaround (hint: consider NOT using this, but using heap allocation for the array):

```
typedef struct depth *depth_p;

struct depth
{
    int number;
    depth_p child[0];
};
```

The trick is, that the following statement is still valid:

```
depth_p d = get_depth();
d->child[5]; // <-- this is still valid
```

In order to use this, you need to create instances of `depth_p` in this (and only this) way:

```
depth_p create_depth(int num_children)
{
    return (depth_p)malloc(
        sizeof(struct depth) + num_children * sizeof(depth_p)
    );
}
```

Firstly, this allocates memory for all the *other* members (`int number`) with `sizeof(struct depth)`. Then, it allocates *additional* memory for the required amount of children by *adding* `num_children * sizeof(depth_p)`.

Don't forget to free your `depth` references with `free`.

Answer (score 0):

Sructs can't have dynamic members so try const int b = 10;

Comment: That won't work either.