# C error: variably modified at the file scope

Tags: c, error-handling, struct

Yeah, so I’m new to C, and I came across an error when dealing with the following code:

```
typedef struct{
    int head;
    int length;
    Customer customer[MAX_LENGTH];

} CustomerCi;
```

And the error that came out was:

> error: variably modified 'customer' at the file scope

How can I fix this?

Comment: i tried those and some of them didnt work and others i didnt understand fully

Comment: They aren't good duplicate targets (and one of them is for Objective-C). The one for C is *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)*.

Comment: See also [the linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/13645936?sort=votes).

Answer (score 1):

Replace MAX_LENGTH with a literal value:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 32
```

for example.

Comment: yeah it works then but later on i need the value of MAX_LENGTH to be able to change.

Comment: the line before the ones i gave already defines MAX_LENGTH as
    
"static const int MAX_LENGTH = 100;"

Comment: You can not change the size of an array in C. Either use pointers with malloc/free or use a [linked list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html).

Comment: oh ok because i was trying to use it to gauge the size of my queue

Comment: Use [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.38/glib-data-types.html) if you do not want to write it on your own. Glib has all you will ever need.

Comment: @user3050546: In C, `static const int MAX_LENGTH = 100;` is still regarded as a 'variable' and `MAX_LENGTH` cannot be used where a constant is required (for example, in case labels, or in array bounds at file scope).  In C++, it would be usable like that.  If you want C++, use it.  But in C, you can't do what you tried.