# "Variably modified 'variable_name' at file scope" with size defined in macro

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, macros, size

I know there is some questions related to this error:
[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194561/error-variably-modified-string-at-file-scope), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292639/c-error-variably-modified-at-the-file-scope), [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925803/variably-modified-variable-name-at-file-scope-error), [question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712592/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope),...

The difference is, I don't use variables to define the size, but macros.

Here is what I do:

```c
#define     SIZE_A      250                      // Real world value
#define     SIZE_B       80                      // Real world value
#define     SCALE         0.25                   // Real world value
#define     TOTAL_A     (uint16_t)(SIZE_A/SCALE)
#define     TOTAL_B     (uint16_t)(SIZE_B/SCALE)
#define     TOTAL       TOTAL_A*TOTAL_B

#define     SIZE_1      (uint16_t)(TOTAL*0.3)


#define     SIZE_2      4000

typedef struct {
    toto_t  toto[TOTAL_A][TOTAL_B];
    foo_t   foo[SIZE_1][SIZE_2];
} bar_t;
```

As you can see, I've got three macros (`SIZE_A`, `SIZE_B`, `SCALE`) which represent real things. From those I define the sizes (`TOTAL_A`, `TOTAL_B`) of a 2 dimensional array (`toto_t toto`), and the total number of cells in this array (`TOTAL`). Then I take a piece of that total (`SIZE_1`) to define the size of an other array I want to create (`foo_t foo`).

This way, [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) throws the error: `Variably modified 'foo' at file scope`. So, I looked at the preprocessor output:

```c
typedef struct {
    toto_t toto[(uint16_t)(250/0.25)][(uint16_t)(80/0.25)];
    foo_t  foo[(uint16_t)((uint16_t)(250/0.25)*(uint16_t)(80/0.25)*0.3)][4000];
} bar_t;
```

As we can see, the preprocessor is doing is job well. All macros are replaced by the literal value. So there is only constant values in the array size.

**My question**

Why can GCC not compute the sizes of the arrays? And is there an option to force it to do the computation?

I compile with this option `-O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Testing:

Create a `test.h` and put the code I posted and add `typedef uint16_t toto_t; typedef uint16_t foo_t;` at the beginning. And create a `test.c` file with:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include "test.h"

int main() {
    printf("hello world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you replace the minimal example I've made for you and that perfectly reproduces your problem by a description of code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the floating value of SCALE.

You can avoid it using fixed point value:

```
#define     SIZE_A      250                      // Real world value
#define     SIZE_B       80                      // Real world value
#define     SCALE         25                   // Real world value
#define     TOTAL_A     (SIZE_A*100/SCALE)
#define     TOTAL_B     (SIZE_B*100/SCALE)
#define     TOTAL       TOTAL_A*TOTAL_B

#define     SIZE_1      (TOTAL*3/10)

#define     SIZE_2      4000

typedef struct {
    toto_t  toto[TOTAL_A][TOTAL_B];
    foo_t   foo[SIZE_1][SIZE_2];
} bar_t;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38062102/8504592) will give you all information about C standard rules.

Comment: I can't change the `SCALE` value, because I use it to do some other computation. It will complexify the reste of the code

Comment: @Phantom: The C standard requires an *integer constant expression* for the array size in this context. It may not contain floating-point operations. If you cannot change `SCALE`, you will have to use some other way of managing the data that does not declare arrays at file scope or in structures that use `SCALE` in their sizes.

Comment: @Phantom Simple: you cannot do what you want to do. Take a look at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054023/c-fixed-size-array-treated-as-variable-size)

Comment: @LPs Yes it answer my question. But I can do want I want. :p From what you propose I just add an other macro `#define SCALE_2 (SCALE/100)`. And then use this macro. Thanks for you answer

Comment: @LPs interestingly it compiles [with clang, but not with gcc](https://www.godbolt.org/z/hQCuFs).

Comment: @Jabberwocky [Not if you compile with the correct standard adding](https://www.godbolt.org/z/GHu6TS) `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`....