# Array size with const variable in C

Tags: c, arrays, scope, constants

I've found an interesting fact, and I didn't understand how is it works.

The following piece of code just works perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const int size = 10;
  int sampleArray[size];
  typedef char String [size];
  return 0;
}
```

Then, I tried to use only and only the constant variable with a global scope, and it's still fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int size = 10;

int main() {
  int sampleArray[size];
  typedef char String [size];
  return 0;
}
```

But, if I change the arrays's scope to global as well, I got the following:

> error: variably modified ‘sampleArray’ at file scope

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int size = 10;
int sampleArray[size];

typedef char String [size];

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

And I didn't get it! If I'd replace the const variable for ex. to `#define` it'd be okay as well. 
I know that the #define variable is preprocessed, and as far as I know the const variable is only read-only. But what does make the global scope after all?

I don't understand what is the problem with the third piece of code, if the second one is just okay.

Comment: Some detail: C has `const` objects but not _constant_ ones.  Although `const` seems to implies _constant_, a `const` object is not _constant_, but more like "this object should not change, but if a change is attempted  - who knows what might happen?"  In C, a true _constant_ is code like `42`, which is an _integer constant_ with the type of `int`.  Thus `const int size = 10;` is not a _constant_ variable.

Comment: The array has no constant size, but is a variable length array.

Comment: Like they said, C has `const` objects, which are actually read-only *variables*. Cf. C++, which has true `const` objects that are actually compile-time *constants*.

Comment: a `const` variable is a variable that the compiler doesn't allow to be modified, but a variable.  Think that value can be unknown at compilation time (as it can come from other file) but the array size must be, so it is forbidden.

Comment: Alternative duplicate: *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLAs) may have only automatic storage duration. VLAs were introduced in [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99).

It is not allowed to declare a VLA with the static storage duration because the size of VLA is determined at the run time (see below).

Before this Standard, you can use either a macro like

```
#define SIZE 10

//...

int a[SIZE];
```

or a enumerator of an enumeration like

```
enum { SIZE = 10; }

//...

int a[SIZE];
```

By the way, you may remove the *const* qualifier and just write

```
int size = 10;
```

instead of

```
const int size = 10;
```

(In C++ you have to use the const qualifier though. In C++, there aren't any VLAs, except that some compilers can have their own language extensions.)

Take into account that the `sizeof` operator for VLAs is calculated at the run time instead of the compile time.

Comment: Thank you I've just started to understand a bit more! However, if I trying without the const, I've got the same error with global scope. But with the #define SIZE 10, it's works.

Comment: @BálintPap As I wrote VLAs may not have static storage duration that all global arrays have.

Comment: A, here we go, alright! Well, never thought about that. Thank you for your explanation! I do appreciate it!