# In C, why can't a const variable be used as an array size initializer?

Tags: c

In the following code, const int cannot be used as an array size:

```
const int sz = 0;
typedef struct
{
   char s[sz];
} st;

int main()
{
   st obj;
   strcpy(obj.s, "hello world");
   printf("%s", obj.s);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because an arrays size has to be a constant, and a const variable is a const variable, not a constant, it means it cannot be changed

Comment: Just a another deficiency in the language.

Comment: ...which was fixed in C++.

Comment: `const int sz;` is an external symbol. It could be overridden at runtime with stuff like LD_PRELOAD. If you added `static`, then I guess it's just an arbitrary restriction of the C language (C++ does away with it after all and there were no major issues with it AFAIK).

Comment: @Mgetz `const` is enough.

Comment: @Mgetz `const` integral variables implicitly become `constexpr` if they have a `constexpr` initializer.

Comment: @Mgetz C++ can have `const` "variables" as compile-time constants. The definition in the code in the question would be such a case.

Comment: You're lucky the code doesn't build, because if it did you would have *undefined behavior* writing to a zero-sized array.

Comment: Other dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40599032/2455888, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11541088/2455888

Comment: The canonical may be *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C, a `const`-qualified variable is not a *constant expression*<sup>1</sup>.  A constant expression is something that can be evaluated at compile time - a numeric literal like `10` or `3.14159`, a string literal like `"Hello"`, a `sizeof` expression, or some expression made up of the same like `10 + sizeof "Hello"`.

For array declarations at file scope (outside the body of any function) or as members of `struct` or `union` types, the array dimension *must* be a constant expression.

For `auto` arrays (arrays declared within the body of a function that are not `static`), you *can* use a variable or expression whose value isn't known until runtime, but only in C99 or later.

---

1. C++ is different in this regard - in that language, a `const`-qualified variable *does* count as a constant expression.

Comment: It cannot be asserted without qualification that a `const`-qualified variable is not a *constant expression*. Although the C standard does not require a *constant expression* to include a `const`-qualified variable, C 2018 6.6 10 says “An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.” (And the same text is in C 1999.)

Comment: C is also different from C++ in that `10` is not called a _numeric literal_, but an _integer constant_.  Aside: C's   _literals_, _string_ and _compound_, can have their addresses taken, unlike an integer constant.

Answer (score 19):

This is because in C `const` actually means *read only*. Quoting [C FAQ 1.18 and 1.19](http://c-faq.com/decl/constasconst.html):

> The const qualifier really means ``read-only''; an object so qualified is a run-time object which cannot (normally) be assigned to. The value of a const-qualified object is therefore not a constant expression in the full sense of the term, and cannot be used for array dimensions, case labels, and the like. (C is unlike C++ in this regard.) When you need a true compile-time constant, use a preprocessor #define (or perhaps an enum).
>
> References: ISO Sec. 6.4 
>   H&S Secs. 7.11.2,7.11.3 pp. 226-7

There are two ways of dealing with it:

1. Use `#define` instead of `const`
2. Use `enum { sz = 12 };`

Answer (score 5):

In a very simple way because the compiler must know the dimension of the array at compilation time and since you can initialize `const variable` at run time you can't do it. So the size of statically declared arrays **must** be a *constant expression* and a `const variable` is not it. For  *constant expression* you should use either a macro (`#define`) or `enum`. That's explicitly for your case (at file scope) and if you use a minimum standard of `c99`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is the answer that got me thinking: "since you can initialize const variable at run time."

Example: void f(int a) { const int size = a; int array[size] = { 0 }; }

size is constant within scope of the function, but can be initialized to any value at runtime, so the array size is not determinable at compile-time.