# Why am I limited to an arbitrary small ( array size when initializing an array with a const length in C?

Tags: c

Note: I have seen [In C, why can't a const variable be used as an array size initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267827/in-c-why-cant-a-const-variable-be-used-as-an-array-size-initializer) already, but this doesn't quite answer my question (or I am not understanding it fully).

This works:

```
int main() {
    const long COUNT = 1048106;
    int nums[COUNT];
    return 0;
}
```

This crashes:

```
int main() {
    const long COUNT = 1048106000;
    int nums[COUNT];
    return 0;
}
```

I have read that this is actually an inappropriate use of `const` to begin with (since it means read-only, not evaluated at compile time).

So I am happy to use `#define` or whatnot instead, but still, it bothers me why this works for some lengths but not but not any higher.

Comment: A typical Unix program has 8 MiB of stack; a typical Windows program has 1 MiB of stack.  Your big size array blows the stack limits out of the water.  Either use a global variable or use dynamic memory allocation.  Remember: the stack is finite and small (and error recovery from a blown stack is problematic at best).  (The first version allocates about 4 MiB on stack; that suggests you're running on a Unix-like system, Linuex for example.  The second version tries to allocate 4 GiB or so on stack — that's not gonna fly anywhere normal.)

Comment: IMO, there use of a VLA has no particular relevance; what matters is the size of the array, not whether it is a VLA or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your array declarations are in fact [variable length array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) declarations. `COUNT` is not a constant expression in C, despite being `const`.

But regardless, the bigger size simply exceeds your implementation's limits, overflowing the call stack where those locals are usually allocated. Though I suspect this behavior will go away should you compile with optimizations. A compiler can easily deduce that `nums` isn't used in your snippet, and remove it entirely.

Comment: Ok, awesome. So this is a stack overflow because the stack doesn't have enough space to address that big an array?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos - Yup. You found its limit. Though it's worth noting the most compilers will let you set the size of the call stack for the generated program, via compilation flags.

Comment: I don't think the behaviour will go away. Even if it is a const.length array, it's still on the stack.

Comment: @glglgl - Compilers are free to optimize as they please under the as-if rule. And if a variable isn't used, the program can be successfully translated as-if the variable was never declared.

Comment: The fact that it is a VLA is tangential to the crash.  Changing the numbers to enumeration constants so it isn't a VLA would still lead to a crash — because the stack size on Unix is normally limited to about 8 MiB and on Windows to about 1 MiB, and the first code tries to allocate about 4 MiB and the second about 4 GiB.  That the first works suggests the OP is running on a Unix-ish system (Linux, macOS, BSD, Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, …).

Comment: @Jonathan - Fine, I rephrased to make the two points stand apart. Anyway, this is all still subject to optimizations. Under O1 neither snippet crashes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's exactly my point. OTOH, if it isn't used, it indeed can be optimized as well – again, no matter if it is VLA or not.