# ANSI C -> Arrays -> Variably modified at file scope

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, ansi-c

While I'm trying to explore possibilities of arrays in C in ANSI, I'm confronted with an issue. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int MAXLIGNE = 5000;
char *ptrlig[MAXLIGNE]; // Ptr sur la ligne de txt // Got an issue:
                        // Variably modified ptrlig @ filescope

int lirelignes(char *ptrlig[], int nlignes);
void ecrirelignes(char *ptrlig[], int nlignes);
void trirapide(char *ptrlig[], int gauche, int droite)
```

Error from the GCC:

```
VARIABLY MODIFIED PTRLIG at FILESCOPE
```

I've seen that 'const' type may create that kind of issues.  I tried to make it like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int MAXLIGNE = 5000;
unsigned char *ptrlig[MAXLIGNE];
```

But that doesn't seem to change anything in this case.

Comment: When you say "ANSI C", do you mean C89 (equivalent to Standard C from ISO, C90), or do you mean 'Standard C' — probably C11 or perhaps C18, depending on how modern your compiler is? If your answer is "I've no idea what you're talking about", then the chances are you're actually using a compiler capable of working with C11 (use `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11`), and should use that instead of `-ansi` (which means `-std=c90`). C90 did not support variable length arrays at all; C99 does support them, but they must defined within a function; C11 provides conditional support for variable length arrays.

Comment: Hey ! I'm talking about C89, but my compiler is definitely c11. I'm using the K&R book but indeed, i may use a C90 compiler, not dumb.. shame on me !

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)

Comment: Re *"VARIABLY MODIFIED PTRLIG at FILESCOPE"*: That is unlikely. What is the literal error mesage?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 4 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of an array defined at file scope **must** be a compile time constant, and the value of another variable does not qualify as such.

If you want to use a name for the length of this array, you'll need to use a macro:

```
#define MAXLIGNE 5000
char *ptrlig[MAXLIGNE];
```

The macro does a direct text substitution, so after the preprocessor stage it is the same as `char *ptrlig[5000];`

Comment: Or an `enum` — see also [`static const` vs `#define` vs `enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032).

Comment: Hey thx for answer me. I tried to use it, but also (may be the compiler c11 that doesnt support this macro) i can't create this macro :/
PS : enum worked but i want to understand why the rest doesnt.

Comment: @SarahConnorh The above should work.  If it doesn't then you must have mistyped something.

Comment: @dbush Yes but using macro. I wanted to use a more local variable this macro is accessible only on one file and callable from everyfunction..