# Compiler error "variable modified 'artikel' at file scope"

Tags: c

I have a program where I get the error:

```
variable modified 'artikel' at file scope
char artikel[ARTNAME];
```

I think I have to add a `#define`, but exactly which one should it be?

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const int ARTNAME = 100;

typedef struct artikel {
    char artikel[ARTNAME];
    int anzahl;
} artikel;

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: `#define ARTNAME 100`. [variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13645936)

Comment: i add #define ARTNAME 100 and now it gives me out----> main.c:5:20: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
    #define ARTNAME 100

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/1Mo69q

Comment: To compile this code, as is, you can turn on a `C99` or above standard. It will not pass in older `C` standards.

Comment: ok thanks, i will try it

Comment: @flavio, you do not *add* the `#define`.  You *change* the existing declaration of `ARTNAME` into a `#define`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)

Comment: You will have to wait for C23 to have a C++ like `constexpr`. Otherwise `const int ARTNAME` is a variable, not literal constant. It's use in declaring `char artikel[ARTNAME];` results in a VLA. `#define ARTNAME 100` requires no storage space -- it is simply a compile-time substitution. `const int ARTNAME = 100;` is a *definition* of the variable `ARTNAME` and requires storage in your program. The subtle resulting difference is you cannot use a `#define` where you need the address of the variable later (it simply doesn't exist)

Answer (score 2):

> I have a program where I get the error: variable modified 'artikel'at file scope char artikel[ARTNAME];

I don't think you have copied the diagnostic accurately.  It is surely complaining about `struct artikel` being *variably* modified.

That is closely related to the issue covered in [Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13645936/2402272).  Specifically, `const` qualification notwithstanding, `ARTNAME` is not a "constant expression" in C, so the type of array `artikel.artikel` and therefore also of the whole `struct artikel` are "variably modified".  Objects with variably modified types cannot be declared at file scope.

> I think I have to add a #define, but I don't understand exactly which one.

The quickest solution would probably be to change this ...

> ```
>     const int ARTNAME = 100;
> ```

... to:

```
#define ARTNAME 100
```