# I am getting an error in my declaration stated "variably modified 'queue' at file scope"?

Tags: c, declaration, definition, variable-length-array

Here is a segment of code.  What should I do to make `queue` global and to take its max size from the user?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max;
int queue[max];

int main()
{
    scanf("%d",&max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)* (see also [the linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/13645936)). Some of them have ***identical*** code. Is this a standard homework assignment?

Answer (score 4):

You declared a variable length array in the file scope

```
int queue[max];
```

because the number of elements in the declaration is not a constant integer expression.

Objects declared in a file scope have static storage duration.  But variable length arrays shall have automatic storage duration. So you may not declare a variable length array in a file scope.

Moreover the variable `max` used in the array declaration is default initialized by zero. In any case even in a block scope you may not declare a variable length array with the number of elements equal to 0.

From the C Standard (6.7.6.2 Array declarators)

> 2 If an identifier is declared as having a variably modified type, it
> shall be an ordinary identifier (as defined in 6.2.3), have no
> linkage, and have either block scope or function prototype scope. If
> an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread
> storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

and

> 5 If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant
> expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope,
> it is treated as if it were replaced by *; otherwise, each time it is
> evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero. The size of each
> instance of a variable length array type does not change during its
> lifetime. Where a size expression is part of the operand of a sizeof
> operator and changing the value of the size expression would not
> affect the result of the operator, it is unspecified whether or not
> the size expression is evaluated.

You should rewrite your program at least like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int max;
    scanf("%d",&max);

    int queue[max];

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t max;
    
    while ( !( scanf( "%zu", &max ) == 1 && max != 0 ) );
    
    int queue[max];
    
    printf( "The size of the array is %zu\n", sizeof( queue ) );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter `10` then the program output might be

```
The size of the array is 40
```

that is `40` is the size of the memory extent occupied by the variable length array `queue` with `10` elements of the type `int`.

Pay attention to that you may not initialize a variable length array in its declaration.

Instead of the variable length array you could allocate an array dynamically using either standard C function `malloc` or `calloc`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common incorrect assumption among people who just started to learn the language.

```
int max;
int queue[max];
```

The size of `queue` **doesn't** become bound to the value of `max`. It's size is fixed as the value of `max` at the moment when the array is created.

So you need to *first* read the value to `max`, and *then* create `queue`. This requires you to create `queue` inside of a function, rather than outside.